# AWS Api Gateway with Lambda integration only works via console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template which sets up an API Gateway with a Lambda integration. When testing the integration via the AWS console it works.

When I attempt to use the HTTP method via Postman or Chrome, the response is *null*.

The full template can be seen here:
https://github.com/mattcanty/musicdown/blob/07b899d5924ab2fcc675cc521706b0c217e4e07e/cloudformation.yaml

I think something is not quite right here:

```
MusicdownsGet:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
    ResourceId: !Ref MusicdownResource
    HttpMethod: GET
    RequestParameters:
      method.request.querystring.filter: true
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    RequestModels:
      application/json: !Ref MusicdownModel
    Integration:
      Type: AWS
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
      Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Lambda.Arn}/invocations
      IntegrationResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
      RequestTemplates:
        application/json: "{ \"filter\": \"$input.params('filter')\" }"
    MethodResponses:
      - StatusCode: 200
```

Comment: Is your Lambda function arn proper in the permission (line 270). If it is not, why don't you try changing it to: 
    FunctionName: !GetAtt Lambda.Arn

Comment: Your CloudFormation template works fine, I just instantiated a complete stack and ran through a sample query. So the issue must be something that was modified separately.

Comment: @jenswalter that's interesting. I'll try deleting and creating again. I've been careful to repeat console changes in the template. Lesson learned.

Comment: API GW provides detailed CloudWatch Logs if you enable them. This would give us a better idea of the root cause, rather than just saying "response is null".